# QCombobox transparent item list stylesheet

Tags: qt, transparency, qt5, qcombobox, qtstylesheets

I try to do list from `QComboBox` I believe it is `QListView/QAbstractItemView` to become transparent. Like in this example I would like to see Pushbutton under the list.

[image]

I tried to put:

`background: transparent`
`background-color: transparent`
`border-style: transparent`
`border-color: transparent`

like everywhere.

Comment: This might be helpful [Remove QListView background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999027/remove-qlistview-background)

Comment: nope, it didn't work I tried this but thanks. It easy to get example for yourself to test solutions simple add `QCombobox` and something under it and few elements to combobox.

Comment: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/15458-Make-the-QComboBox-popup-translucent-or-transparent your view is transparent but other things not: QComboBoxPrivateContainer I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I asked qt support and and answer was that is not easy to do this in stylesheet and suggested approach was to change opacity property of the pop-up window where the combobox list is drawn:

```
if (combo->view()->parentWidget())
    combo->view()->parentWidget()->setWindowOpacity(0.5);
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much!